# function pointers in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was trying to figure out function pointers. My code looks like this I have a `file.h` where I have a struct that hast 2 members

```
typedef struct _node_ {
    char* string;
    int (*compare)(int a, int b);
} node
```

in that same file, I have a prototype for a function called:

```
void init_with_function_pointer(node* list, int (*comp)(int x, int y));
```

then in my `file.c`, I define the function :

```
void init_with_function_pointer(node* list, int (*comp)(int x, int y)){
    node_init(list);
    list->compare = comp;
}
```

and in my `main.c`

```
int main(){
    node tree;
    init_with_function_pointer(&tree, /* what should I pass here */)
}
```

And that function that I need to point to should be defined in `file.c`

but I can't get it to work, if I define the function in main and a pass it, then it works, but if I try to use `extern` for that same function which I define in `file.c` the compiler tells me `comp` is not defined.

and this is my function that i would like to point to:

```
extern int comp(int x,int y) {
  if (x < y) {
    return -1;
  } else if(x == y) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Just put the name of the function there.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that you're not linking with the `file.o` when you compile.

Comment: Can you add the compare function declarations in `file.c,h` and `main.c` (esp. with the `extern`)?

Comment: Do you have a prototype for the function in `file.h`?

Comment: OT: No need to explicitly specify `extern`, as function are `extern` by default.

Answer (score 2):

You need a prototype for the `comp` function in `file.h`:

```
int comp(int, int);
```

Then in `main()` you write:

```
init_with_function_pointer(&tree, comp);
```